# How to parse only certain properties and values from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a JSON. Example below,

```
[
{
    "id": "(error)",
    "raw": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.",
    "code": "W030",
    "evidence": "v",
    "line": 1,
    "character": 1,
    "scope": "(main)",
    "reason": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."
  },
  {
    "id": "(error)",
    "raw": "Missing semicolon.",
    "code": "W033",
    "evidence": "v",
    "line": 1,
    "character": 2,
    "scope": "(main)",
    "reason": "Missing semicolon."
  }
]
```

I just need to print something like the following:

- Reason 1: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
  expression.
- Reason 2: Missing semicolon.

I have a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EyeJeSo/1/edit). How can I just parse only the "reason" properties/values and how many times it is occurring?

Comment: `jsonobj.each(function(){ console.log(reason); })`

Comment: Dipesh, Both JavaScript/jQuery is fine. Can you please provide a fiddle or maybe update the jsBin I have above. That will be very helpful.

Comment: Froddo Baggins - As my suggested edit has been rejected - Do you want your answer in [pure javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)? as your [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EyeJeSo/1) uses the later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to print errors try this:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#js").keyup(function(){
        jsSource = $("#js").val();
        JSHINT(jsSource);
        result = JSON.stringify(JSHINT.errors, null, 2);
        //storage for reasons
        var errors = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < JSHINT.errors.length; i++){
            //reason collecting
            errors.push((i + 1) + ') ' + JSHINT.errors[i].reason);
        }
        //print reasons
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = errors.join(', ');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = 
    [
    {
        "id": "(error)",
        "raw": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.",
        "code": "W030",
        "evidence": "v",
        "line": 1,
        "character": 1,
        "scope": "(main)",
        "reason": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."
      },
      {
        "id": "(error)",
        "raw": "Missing semicolon.",
        "code": "W033",
        "evidence": "v",
        "line": 1,
        "character": 2,
        "scope": "(main)",
        "reason": "Missing semicolon."
      }
    ] ;

alert(obj[0].reason);
alert(obj[1].reason);
```

Comment: Perhaps because it is logging it to the console, rather than `alert`'ng the user?

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the array object and search for the values you need:

```
var obj = [
    {
        "id": "(error)",
        "raw": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.",
        "code": "W030",
        "evidence": "v",
        "line": 1,
        "character": 1,
        "scope": "(main)",
        "reason": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."
      },
      {
        "id": "(error)",
        "raw": "Missing semicolon.",
        "code": "W033",
        "evidence": "v",
        "line": 1,
        "character": 2,
        "scope": "(main)",
        "reason": "Missing semicolon."
      }
    ] ;

$.each(obj, function(key, value){    
    if (value && value.hasOwnProperty('reason')){
        console.log(value['reason']);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 For utilising JQuery like the OP seems to be using & Implementing some error prevention.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this way...

step 1: convert json to array.

```
var tags = $.parseJSON(json_string);
```

step 2: remove all `'raw'` to error string array and print them

```
var errors= new Array();
var error_no = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
     var element = tags [i];
     var e_String = 'Reason '+error_no;
     error_no++;
     error.e_String = element.raw;
}
```

Comment: OP's Demo seems to be using JQuery. Might want to alter answer to suit.